# Remote control while on the lock screen (Session or service based remote control)

Tags: remote

I want to remotely connect from a windows to an ubuntu, and I don't want the ubuntu user see what am I doing in the  ubuntu pc while I am connected remotely from a windows pc. If the ubuntu pc is locked then the ubuntu pc user only sees the lock screen while I am connected the ubuntu desktop.

Is it possible?

Thanks.